# Site Builder Architecture

Tags: architecture, scalability, builder

Without talking about technologies, I'm very curious about designing a Site Builder.

How does a website like [jimdo](https://www.jimdo.com), or [wix.com](https://www.wix.com) work ?

Ideally I would like to

- make a **Uniq API** (backend)
- serve many front clients (with front end technologies such as **ReactJS**)

Should the *backend* serve the *front* parts (Through a *Database* storage) ?

Or create and instantiate the files on the FS for each clients ?

I was thinking about dynamically creating *buckets* on **AWS S3** containing the website
Redirecting each *subdomains* to those *buckets*, would be very scalable but not really easy to update.

I have very no idea about how to **design** a **Site builder**, where you can instantiate *subwebsite on the fly*, with a **high-scalability** factor and **customizable** for each served front ?

Answer (score 1):

Generally these sites are building a static front-end (HTML/JavaScript/CSSS) which is being stored and served from a location (like S3).  They almost definitely will have both a Database to store things like user metadata, site parameters etc, and a static hosting location (like S3) that scales.

I don't understand why S3 would not be easily updateable..  You will need to capture all the parameters that go into generating the site so that they can come back and regenerate it when they add/change functionality.